# RAID setup - possible to disconnect a drive?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, raid, software-raid

this may be a silly question for some, but I rather ask then to be sorry after losing my data :-] I am just playing with RAID config on my Intel X58 ICH10R chipset mobo with Windows 8.1 and I found out RAID5 is unfortunately very slow with writes, so now I have RAID 10 with 4 500GB drives which seems to work great. The OS is on a different (5th drive) which is not in a RAID array. But I don't have any experience with non standard situations like what happens for example if I would disconnect one drive (to simulate a drive failure) and just start a computer? Does the RAID utility which appears before OS boot detect a problem and start doing something before letting the OS start? Or will it boot into windows and then the Intel Rapid Storage driver would say something and try to rebuild or repair the array? What if I then switch the PC off and just connect the drive back. Would the RAID controller accept it into array and start working as before or would I have to recreate the whole array or something? Thank you in advance for your patient and clear answer or link to some good articles on the topic ;)

Comment: As you have a redundant setup the computer should recognise that an array element has failed or is not present and continue to work - only if the array is still stable to operate. If your motherboard supports "hot-swap" drives then you could (in theory) plug in/remove with the PC on. Most don't so be very careful!

Comment: Most will detect the issue before windows loads. if the failure occurs while in Windows, then the rapid storage driver will detect it and keep things running until you replace the disc, most consumer raid controllers are NOT hot swapable, so don't unplug-plug while powered up.